# How do I align links to left and right in a Bootstrap 3 navigation in MVC 5

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller, razor

I'm trying to get my Navigation Bar [to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eor05.jpg). However the text won't align to the right side of the screen seemingly no matter what changes I make to the base layout code.

My  html code is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @if (Session["Logged_In"] == null)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "OUsers")</li>
            <li class="navbar-right">@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "OUsers")</li>
            <li class="navbar-right">@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "OUsers")</li>                       
        }
        @if (Session["Logged_In"] != null)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "LoggedIndex", "OUsers")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete Account", "DeleteProfile", "OUsers")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit Profile", "EditProfile", "OUsers")</li>
            <li style="float:right">@Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "SignOut", "OUsers")</li>

        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

This isn't the full Layout code granted however it's what I've actually edited and seems relevant to text alignment. Also my "navbar-right" class consists of only `float: right;` and `text-align: right;`

The strange thing is that when I inspect the Login and Create actionlinks on the website the "navbar-right" class is applied yet there is no alignment changed. It may be worth noting I tried putting the css class within the actionlink parameters and nothing changed and I also attmepted a new division with navbar right but that seemed to align Login under the Home actionlink which was also bizarre to me.

Comment: Can you try adding flex-sm-row-reverse class to the top level div with navbar-collapse collapse? (and remove the inline CSS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using Bootstrap 3. Then this will work

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `navbar-nav` class have `float:left` property with it which align all the nav to left side
try to override
[image]